# How to do batch learning for Gaussian Mixture Models?

Tags: machine-learning, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I have a huge dataset of features on which I want to fit a Gaussian Mixture Model using standard expectation maximization, as it is implemented by sklearn. Since not all features fit into the memory at once, I need to train my GMM iteratively, i.e. one batch after the other. What is the best approach to do this? Just go for GMM.fit(batch) for each batch? Maybe use a smaller number of iterations for the EM algorithm? Anymore thoughts, ideas, or even better references therefore?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This question has been asked on [Stackoverflow a while back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29095769/sklearn-gmm-on-large-datasets) .

Since scikit-learn did not extend their implementation of Gaussian mixtures with a `partial_fit` method [(as was the case with other models in the past)](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html#incremental-learning) I would suggest applying the solution in the accepted answer -  sample a subset of the data that fits into the available memory and learn the model for that.

Given the sample isn't too small, it should represent the original distribution well enough.